# How to precache files from AWS to my React app with service-worker?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, service-worker

I'm making a game on React and I want to precache all files from AWS to user machine and then use them from serviceworker.

I found such code

```
import React, { Component, lazy } from 'react';

import AvatarComponent from './AvatarComponent';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      details: false
    }
  }

  showDetails() {
    this.setState({ details: true });
  }

  render() {
    const { details } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className="App">
        { !details && <button onClick={() => this.showDetails()}>CLICK ME</button> }
        { details &&   
          <div>
            <AvatarComponent />
          </div> 
        }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

in AvatarComponent I have

```
import React from 'react';
import imageSrc from './pupper.jpg';

const AvatarComponent = () => (
  <img alt="Puppy" src={imageSrc} />
)

export default AvatarComponent;
```

This app works as expected - when I click on **CLICK ME** button I see that *pupper.jpg* image is loaded from serviceworker.

What do I need to do to precache and save images, audios and videos stored on Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3)?

Here is working example that I have https://glitch.com/~daffy-snowy-suggestion

Comment: It's difficult to find a universal solution because each gamer's web browser is different. And a prefetch will download data which takes up gamer bandwidth. Some web browsers offer local storage for those gamers maybe [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a handy place to cache images though it's not an LRU so the app must manage the cache and the app must store the images and audio as strings.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 is not a CDN in that it caches files. Use CloudFront for caching files stored on S3.